# What is a general kind of tensor product of things with a commutative operation?

Tags: category-theory, modules, tensor-products, universal-algebra, monoidal-categories

Consider the usual tensor product of modules.

> What is a good generalization of this tensor product?

The answer here is not supposed to be "a monoidal structure", I want the gist of *this particular* tensor product.

I know (vaguely) that [there is such a tensor product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory) for every category of $\mathsf{Set}$-models of a *commutative* algebraic theory. I wouldn't be surprised, if there was also one for commutative monoids in a symmetric monoidal category (with some properties).

But specifically, I want to take products *also* of things like *ordered* commutative monoids and similar variations of this theme (ideally, I have one construction that works for all these things).

Comment: A "good generalization" of the bicategory of bimodules over rings $R,S,...$ is the (multi)bicategory of profunctors; that's maybe not what you want, but my feeling is that the leap "modules" $\mapsto$ "profunctors" is shorter than the "modules" $\mapsto$ "monoids in $\bf LawTh$"...

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Well, I want my example (ordered commutative monoids) to work (assuming that it can work).

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Actually, I gave the wrong impression. Ignore the "bimodule" bit, I don't want to get the entire structure of this bicategory. Let's stick to $(R,R)$-bimodules and the like.

Comment: I don't understand the "but" and "also" in the last sentence: aren't ordered commutative monoids the commutative monoids of the symmetric monoidal category of small thin categories?

Comment: @Pece Yes, they are. But the question is: How do I get the tensor product for commutative monoids? (one way or the other or perhaps even completely differently). - Ah yes, the "but" and "also" mainly refers to the fact that in the first idea sketched (commutative algebraic theories) only the case of models in $\mathsf{Set}$ is "well-known" (I would need models in $\mathsf{Pos}$ e.g.)

Comment: Maybe you know this, but an algebraic theory $\mathcal T$ is commutative when for any model $M$ of $\mathcal T$ in a category $\mathcal C$, the operations $M^n\to M$ in $\mathcal C$ are also $T$-homomorphism from the model $T$-module structure $M^n$ to the $T$-model structure $M$. Because of this, we have canonical lifts of the representable functors $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathcal C}(T)}(-,M)\colon\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathcal C}(T)\to\mathsf{Set}$ to functors $\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathcal C}(T)}(-,M)\colon\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathcal C}(T)\to\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathsf{Set}}(T)$.

Comment: In the case where $\mathcal C=\mathsf{Set}$, then the tensor product functors $-\otimes_{\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathsf Set}(T)} M$ can be defined as the left adjoint of $\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathsf C}(T)}(-,M)$. To obtain a general definition, you can take $\mathcal C$ to be any cartesian closed category so that the representable functors are valued in $\mathcal C$. This doesn't tell you how to compute the tensor products, beyond chasing adjunctions around, but maybe you can still get the tensor product $N\otimes M$ as an appropriate quotient of the coproduct of the models $N$ and $M$.